# How to save and restore ResourceBase?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm add a self-defined ops and using ResourceMgr to a create child class of ResourceBase to store some status, and how to write the status into checkpoint file.

```
class FeatureTransformMap : public ResourceBase {
public:
    FeatureTransformMap(int32_t max_feature_count) : max_feature_count_(max_feature_count), feature_index_(0) {
        cout<<"Max feature count is:"<<max_feature_count_<<endl;
    }
    string DebugString() {return "FeatureTransformMap";}

    int32_t GetFeatureIndex(const string& feature) {
        {
            mutex_lock l(mu_);
            feature_index_ += 1;
        }
        return feature_index_;
    }



private:
    tensorflow::mutex mu_;
    uint32_t feature_index_ GUARDED_BY(mu_);
    const uint32_t max_feature_count_;
};
```

as in code above, how can I write feature_index_  to checkpoint files.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic way to save a `tensorflow::ResourceBase` instance, but you can implement your own checkpointing support as follows:

1. Define methods on your `FeatureTransformMap` class that serialize the state of the map to, and deserialize it from, one or more `tensorflow::Tensor` objects. For an example, see  [`MutableHashTableOfScalars::ExportValues()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_op.cc#L212) and [`MutableHashTableOfScalars::ImportValues()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_op.cc#L207).
2. Implement new TensorFlow `OpKernel` classes that invoke your serialization and deserialization methods. For an example, see [`LookupTableExportOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_op.cc#L818) and [`LookupTableImportOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_op.cc#L835).
3. In Python, implement a subclass of [`BaseSaverBuilder.SaveableObject`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L103) for your resource, which includes invocations of your new ops. For an example, see [`MutableDenseHashTable._Saveable`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py#L1650).
4. In Python, when you create an instance of your resource, add it to the collection of `tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS`. For an example, see how this is done for `MutableDenseHashTable` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4e3864cb351da6f639b5adfa5a375d826ade26b4/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py#L1357).